# Cannot Run batch file from remote drive?

Tags: python, batch-file

I am not sure what the issue is. I am trying to run a batch file from my teams Y: drive and I am receiving the following error

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Here is my code:

```
filepath = 'Y:\\filepath\\file.bat'

p = subprocess.Popen(filepath)

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

fail
```

but when I run it just from my C: drive it works just fine?

```
filepath = 'C:\\filepath\\file.bat'

p = subprocess.Popen(filepath)

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

works
```

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: No idea, sorry. This is not a batch file within the SO definition which specifies windows `cmd` (and a few others). You've demonstrated the wisdom of cut-and-paste admirably :)

Comment: Try setting `shell=True`. And since you want stdout and stderr, try:

Comment: `p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: Thanks i tried shell before and although it fixed the error unfortunately the batch file still does not execute.

Comment: Does the real `filepath` have any space characters in it? If so, you may need to wrap it in double quote characters.

Comment: The actualy file path works fine I am able to read and write to files in the Y: drive but for some reason cannot execute this batch file?

Comment: It could be a permissions problem in that case. Try running the Python code from an administrator's account.